# NModbus C# .Net 8.0 - TCP Slave - 1st parameter (float) at Holding Address 40001 only has resolution of only 0.125, rest work OK

Tags: c#, .net, tcp, modbus, slave

Trying to get NMOdbus to work on a .Net 8.0 Console app, and all works OK. I am able to set the data in the dataStore, and then using Modbus Poll, I am able to read the data. I am new to .Net, so excuse me if there are any glaring errors.

The only issue I am finding is that the first parameter at address 40001 only changes by increments of 0.125, while the rest of the parameters have the full resolution. If I start the data at address 40003, then that behavior is still the same (so I don't think the issue is the Modbus Poll software)

Here is a sample of the data that should be present

```
Param 0 = 25.671875
Param 0 = 25.671875
Param 0 = 25.671875
Param 0 = 25.671875
Param 0 = 25.664062
Param 0 = 25.664062
Param 0 = 25.671875
Param 0 = 25.671875
Param 0 = 25.664062
Param 0 = 25.664062
Param 0 = 25.671875
Param 0 = 25.671875
Param 0 = 25.671875
Param 0 = 25.671875
Param 0 = 25.671875
Param 0 = 25.664062
Param 0 = 25.664062
Param 0 = 25.664062
Param 0 = 25.664062
Param 0 = 25.664062
Param 0 = 25.664062
Param 0 = 25.671875
Param 0 = 25.664062
Param 0 = 25.671875
Param 0 = 25.671875
Param 0 = 25.664062
```

However, the modbus poll will only read 25.625 (and will only change as stated by increments of 0.125)

My code is listed below

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection.Emit;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Configuration;
using NModbus;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Numerics;



//
// Modbus
//  Rgisters
//      Float
//          2 registers per device parameter
//          starting register =     40001 -  parameter 0
//                                  40003 - parameter 1
//                                  40005 - parameter 2
//                                  ..
//                                  40099 - parameter 49
//

namespace CommIoT
{
    public partial class Program
    {
        private IModbusFactory _modbusFactory;
        private IModbusSlaveNetwork _slaveNetwork;
        private TcpListener _tcpListener;
        private int numParams = 28;


        public double GetParamResult(int param)
        {
            return deviceData.parameters[param].result;
        }


        public void ModbusServer()
        {
            _modbusFactory = new ModbusFactory();
        }
        public void CreateServer(IPAddress ip, int port)
        {
            _tcpListener = new TcpListener(ip, port);
            _tcpListener.Start();
            _slaveNetwork = _modbusFactory.CreateSlaveNetwork(_tcpListener);
        }
        public void AddSlave(byte unitId)
        {
            var slave = _modbusFactory.CreateSlave(unitId);

            _slaveNetwork.AddSlave(slave);
            ISlaveDataStore dataStore = _slaveNetwork.GetSlave(unitId).DataStore;
            ReadData(dataStore);
        }
        public void StartServer()
        {
            _slaveNetwork.ListenAsync();
        }

        public void EWModbusServer()
        {
            // create the modbus server
            ModbusServer();
            CreateServer(IPAddress.Any, 502);
            AddSlave(1);
            StartServer();
        }

        public async void ReadData(ISlaveDataStore _dataStore)
        {
            while (numParams == 0)
            {
                await Task.Delay(5000);     // wait for stability of the data
            }


            ushort[] a1 = new ushort[numParams * 2];
            ushort[] sArr = new ushort[2];


            while (true)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < numParams; i++)
                {
                    float f = (float)GetParamResult(i);

                    if (i == 0)
                        Console.WriteLine("Param 0 = " + f.ToString());

                    ModbusToUnsignedShortArray((float)f, ref sArr);

                    a1[i * 2] = sArr[0];
                    a1[(i * 2) + 1] = sArr[1];
                }
                _dataStore.HoldingRegisters.WritePoints(1, a1);

                // set the Holding registers
                // enter all the parameters into the data store
                await Task.Delay(1000);
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _slaveNetwork?.Dispose();
            _slaveNetwork = null;
            _tcpListener?.Stop();
            _tcpListener = null;
        }



        public float ModbusToFloat(ushort[] args)
        {
            if (args.Length != 2)
                throw new ArgumentException("Input Array length invalid - Array langth must be '2'");

            var highValue = BitConverter.IsLittleEndian ? args[1] : args[0];
            var lowValue = BitConverter.IsLittleEndian ? args[0] : args[1];


            byte[] highRegisterBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(highValue);
            byte[] lowRegisterBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(lowValue);

            byte[] doubleBytes = {
                         highRegisterBytes[0],
                         highRegisterBytes[1],
                         lowRegisterBytes[0],
                         lowRegisterBytes[1],
         };

            return BitConverter.ToSingle(doubleBytes, 0);
        }

        public void ModbusToUnsignedShortArray(float fValue, ref ushort[] reg)
        {
            var value = BitConverter.SingleToInt32Bits(fValue);
            ushort low = (ushort)(value & 0x0000ffff);
            ushort high = (ushort)((value & 0xffff0000) >> 16);

            var highRegister = BitConverter.IsLittleEndian ? low : high;
            var lowRegister = BitConverter.IsLittleEndian ? high : low;

            reg[0] = lowRegister;
            reg[1] = highRegister;
        }

    }




}
```

As stated,

I tried changing the start address of the Holding registers

```
    _dataStore.HoldingRegisters.WritePoints(3, a1);
```

That did not work - same 0.125 inc/dec - but all the registers now start at 3,5,7 etc

The printed data in

```
                   if (i == 0)
                        Console.WriteLine("Param 0 = " + f.ToString());
```

Shows that the resolution should be about 0.01, not 0.125

(Modbus poll is defined as LittleEndian ByteSwap to get the correct visualization)

Comment: I am using this NuGet package https://github.com/NModbus/NModbus

Comment: Can you please provide a [minimal, reproducible, example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Alternatively show us the raw data sent/received (you might find [this converter](https://www.scadacore.com/tools/programming-calculators/online-hex-converter/) useful - my guess would be that it's an endianness issue).

Comment: Your code didn't define `GetParamResult` nor `numParams`, and main function is also missing here. The code you provided is not reproducible example, please update your question to include the necessary information.

Comment: GetParamResult - is a function outside of this code - it returns a double. numParams is an int, also defined elsewhere - in my particular case it is 28. I added them to the original question

Comment: If it were an endianness issue, should not all the HoldingRegisters exhibit the same issue. In my case, it is only the first register, the rest are OK. I will try to get a Wireshark report and post it here later today, or tomorrow

Comment: "tcp.payload": "45:56:00:00:00:73:01:03:70:00:00:41:d0:70:00:41:cc:76:fb:41:cb:c9:8b:42:c6:00:00:3e:1b:e8:34:42:8c:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:43:70:00:00:42:84:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00",
          "tcp.pdu.size": "121"
        },

Comment: This is the wireshark output for the payload - the first register starts at 41:d0:70:00, and each register is the next 4 bytes after that. By a float to hex converter, it seems nmodbus is sending the correct data, as the value of the first register is 26.0390625 when converted. This is weird, as Modbus poll is a commercial program.

Comment: `41 d0 70 00` float big endian (ABCD) = `26.0546875` by my calculation?. Again it will be easier to help if you simplify the example considerably (make it something we can run, by removing references to functions that are not included and just return a a single float - i.e. 2 registers).

Comment: Thanks for the help, yes I tried the conversion with https://gregstoll.com/~gregstoll/floattohex/ and it is 26.05.47. In any case, the data is being correctly sent by nmodbus, and the issue seems to be wit the Modbus poll program. I would tag your suggestion to get the raw data as the key to solving this. At least the code serves as an example for a functioning nmodbus client (very few examples out there - mostly master examples)